# "ubuntu terminal"-like console for windows?

Tags: windows-vista, terminal, console, selection, transparency

I have to work in vista for a while and I am searching for a console that will look much like ubuntu terminal. I want to be able to make the *background transparent*, change the *font color*, use *keyboard shortcuts* for copy and paste and I most of all I want to be able to *select lines* from the console session.

Searching I found two consoles that have pros and cons, but none of them gives the possibility to select input or output code lines.

The first one is [`Console2`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) but the bad thing is that it cannot be maximized;it only works in a small window. There is the possibility to adjust the size but it's not really handy.

The second console is [`Console Emulator`](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) but apart from the fact that I cannot select code lines, when I use a specific program(`root` from CERN that is) the font color changes from the custom to the default.

Is there a console in wondows that will do the following

1. transparent background
2. Change Font Color
3. keyboard shortcuts
4. select input or output code lines with mouse

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: "...apart from the fact that I cannot select code lines, when I use a specific program(root from CERN that is) the font color changes from the custom to the default." What?

Comment: @Maximus: Which part don't you understand? It's crazy I know, but the default font color is white and I use green. When I use `root`(it's a console program, without GUI) the font color changes to white!

Comment: What does it do? ConEmu doesn't change font color "itself".

Comment: But it does! Check it out http://i.imgur.com/VREhBsC.png

Comment: From your screen I only can conclude that color is changed by "root" app. Without this app and without your ConEmu settings I can't help you. Why you have not reported this problem, hm?

Comment: @Maximus: Report it?To whom?The developer? Perhaps it's a good idea to do! But my question doesn't have to do with that bug;it has to do with an ubuntu terminal-like console for windows, that will allow me to select input or output lines. Do you know any one?

Comment: ConEmu, of course. What it'd the problem with selection, I wonder? And, BTW, I'm developer.

Comment: @Maximus: You are the developer? ha ha ha!!! You are now convinved about the font color bug? Anyway, about the selection of code lines see this example http://i.imgur.com/9IGGx5n.jpg in ubuntu's terminal I can highlight an copy code lines.

Comment: Joking, ha ha ha!!! There is no bug! Until you not provide required info. Asked several times already! Selection? Have you even tried it??? http://conemu-maximus5.googlecode.com/svn/files/ConEmuTextSelection2.png

Comment: The root app can be found here http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/production-version-534 while the `.xml` file is http://pastebin.com/xQj9Yvpf .As far as the selection is concerned, I cannot do it with the mouse...The only way to do it was by using `Shift`+`LeftArrow`...

Comment: I have just found out... It's working with `Alt` and mouse... But what about the "bug"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11929/discussion-between-maximus-and-thanos)

Answer (score 1):

Try [MINTTY](https://mintty.github.io/). You can look for installation tutorials online. Once you have installed it, you can open the options dialog box by right clicking the top bar of the terminal.

The options provide all 4 feature as shown you are looking for. 
This is how my terminal looks like now.

[image: SnapShot of Mintty]

Comment: Could you quote the relevant parts from your link? This is in case it gets removed in the future. Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I use and highly recommend [cmder](http://cmder.net/).

Comment: The question is off-topic because requests for product recommendations tend to attract spammy lists of products with little qualitative information, like random Google hits (like this).  [From LQP review queue](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/564030)  Can you expand your answer a bit?  At least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.